# Existe-t-il en français l'équivalent de l'expression « surf English » ?

Tags: expressions, argot, niveau-de-langue

Les communications internationales mènent les jeunes à parler de façon plutôt rapide que correcte je voudrais savoir s'il existe en France l'analogue de l'expression *"surf English"*  pour nommer cette sorte de langue.

Answer (score 4):

Je crois que ce que cherches à connaitre Yurij73 c’est ce que l’on appelle les *argots*. En France existe le *jargo* (ou « Français branché ») ainsi que le *verlan* ou les autres procédés argotiques comme le *louchebem* encore que ces derniers ne se fondent pas sur un lexique propre mais détournent de façon formalisée le lexique commun. Mais souvent des sociolectes argotiques couplent ces procédés néologiques avec d’autres comme l’emprunt aux langues étrangères, particulièrement les dialectes magrébins et l’anglais (ou le *franglais* un autre dérivé du français) de l’arabe dans l’argot français contemporain.
Enfin, on peut citer des cas particulier où l’argot se superpose au jargon comme avec l’argot scolaire et ses variantes spécifiques à certaines institutions comme l’*argot normalien* ou l’*Argad'z*

Hors de France, il existe le *Joual* au Québec, le *camfranglais* au Cameroun.

Par ailleurs, il y’a les *créoles* qui sont au français ce que les pidgins sont à l’anglais mais il s’agit d’avantage de variante du français, ou de dialectes que de registres familiers d’une autre langue.

Answer (score 1):

Les langes français sont de très bonne qualité, mais j'ai bien peur que la politique de StackExchange ne nous permette pas de citer les marques préférées de nos bambins.

Concernant l'analogue à "surf English", j'utiliserais "français jeune" (approximatif), "français de la rue" (légèrement péjoratif), ou bien simplement "français parlé" (approximatif). Mais toutes ces traductions perdent un tantinet du sens présent en anglais.

Comment: Alors, "français jeune" s'il n'y a pas de choix plus spécialisee. Est-ce que la politique SE interdit des mots argotiques pour de bon?

Comment: De quelle politique parle-t-on ?

Comment: SE = StackExchange

Comment: Mais okw, en quoi y’a-t-il besoin de parler de marque ? Et puis, Stack ne s’oppose qu’à la promotion gratuite pas à la discutions au sujet d’une marque si elle est à propos (encore que là, je ne vois pas comment).

Comment: @Fauve Il est vrai. C'était un fâcheux calembour de ma part. Que voulez-vous. Je plaisante, je plaisante. Bien que jamais avec l'humour.

Comment: @Yurij73 Pour clarifier, je tentais l'insertion d'une boutade se référant au titre précédant l'edit, contenant le mot "lange".